# Why does %26 get decoded to & when passed as a parameter to a JavaScript function from a link?

Tags: javascript, html

We've got a menu in out web app that uses `<a>` tags to load pages in the main frame.

A typical item in the menu would be something like:

```
<a target="mainframe" href="/servlet1?param1=val1&parma2=servlet2?s2p1=val2%26s2p2=val3&param3=val4">Menu Item 1</a>
```

We needed to add some JavaScript validation before the link is requested so I changed it to:

```
<a target="mainframe" href="javascript:validate('/servlet1?param1=val1&parma2=servlet2?s2p1=val2%26s2p2=val3&param3=val4')">Menu Item 1</a>
```

(I know that `javascript:function` in a link is bad practice but we use a 3rd party library to generate the menu so I can't change this part of the code)

Servlet1 expects:
param1='val1'
param2='servlet2?s2p1=val2%26s2p2=val3'
param3='val4'

Servlet1 then forwards to the value of param2 so Servlet2 expects:
s2p1='val2'
s2p2='val3'

However when I put an `alert` in my validate function to check what is passed in:

```
function validate(href) {
    alert(href);

    ...validation code...
}
```

it is giving:
/servlet1?param1=val1&parma2=servlet2?s2p1=val2**&**s2p2=val3&param3=val4 (note the bold `&` which was `%26` in the above function call)

The `%26` is getting converted to an `&` when it is passed into the JS function which would not normally happen until the request is forwarded to `Servlet2`. Because the `%26` has already been changed to an `&` the `s2p2` request parameter gets picked up by `servlet1` instead of `servlet2`.

Basically my question is why does the `%26` get converted to a `&` at this point just by passing it as a parameter to the function from the `href` attribute when if you do  `onClick="validate('/servlet1?param1=val1&parma2=servlet2?s2p1=val2%26s2p2=val3&param3=val4')"`
it stays as `%26` as you'd expect?

Comment: There shouldn't be two "?" in the URL

Comment: The 2nd "?" is just part of the param2 who's value is `servlet2?s2p1=val2%26s2p2=val3`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<a target="mainframe" href="javascript:validate('/servlet1?param1=val1&parma2=servlet2?s2p1=val2%26s2p2=val3&param3=val4')">Menu Item 1</a>
```

Urgh. You have a URL, embedded in a URL, all embedded in another URL! That's too many levels of escaping for the human mind to cope with.This:

```
javascript:validate('/servlet1?param1=val1&parma2=servlet2?s2p1=val2%26s2p2=val3&param3=val4')
```

is itself a URL. Albeit a `javascript:` pseudo-URL, which you should never use. It is decoded to the JavaScript command:

```
validate('/servlet1?param1=val1&parma2=servlet2?s2p1=val2&s2p2=val3&param3=val4')
```

at which point you have already lost the %26. Now when you use that as a URL itself, it will fail.

Avoid multiple-encoding problems by moving the scripting out into a JavaScript block (or external script) instead of an HTML attribute:

```
<a target="mainframe" class="validateme" href="/servlet1?param1=val1&amp;parma2=servlet2?s2p1=val2%26s2p2=val3&amp;param3=val4">Menu Item 1</a>
```

(Note here also the necessary HTML-escaping of ampersands.) Then from script do:

```
// find 'validateme' links and add event handler
//
for (var i= document.links; i-->0;)
    if (document.links[i].className==='validateme')
        document.links[i].onclick= validate;
```

Then in your validate function simply return `true` if all is OK and you want the link to be followed, or `false` to stop it.

Comment: Thanks for a clear explanation of why it was happening - because it is treated as a pseudo URL by the browser it is decoded at that point when it is clicked. 

I didn't want to use javascript: in a URL but due to using a 3rd party library to generate the menu as stated in the question didn't think I could do it any way apart from providing the library with updated links that call the function. Your example has shown me a better way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I also hit this issue and I had no idea what was going on.Please note that double urlencoding also works (i.e. %2526)

Answer (score 7):

No, the `%26` is (correctly) interpreted as & when the HTML file is first read into the browser, and not when passed into the JavaScript function. If you want the literal sequence of characters "percent two six", then you must encode that as `%2526`.

Comment: I've checked that already. If that was the case then why before I made the above change does clicking on the link and inspecting the value of param2 within Servlet1 show `servlet2=s2p1=val2%26s2p2=val3` and the `s2p2` param correctly gets through to Servelt2? Similarly if I hover over the link it still shows %26 in the status bar.

Comment: That helped me a lot! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `javascript:` protocol is still considered a valid URL, so the browser is properly encoding it.  It's easy to decode it in your Javascript...

```
alert(decodeURIComponent(href));
```

Comment: It is already decoded in the JavaScript so decodeURIComponent(href)=href in the function.