# Escaping HTML Encoded Characters while submitting button/forms

Tags: php, html, url, urlencode

My need is to send multiple values when a user clicks a button which uses GET METHOD.
Since multiple values are to be sent, I am using an argument as follows:

```
$argument='var2=value2&var3=value3';
echo "<button value='value1&$argument&' type='submit' name='var1'>Send</button>";
```

Essentially, the button tag in HTML has a restriction that it can send ONLY one name-value pair. In this case, it will send `name='var1'` and corresponding value as `value1`. Hence, I am appending the other name-value pairs through the PHP $argument variable. In this case, `var2=value2&var3=value3` are getting appended, and sent.

All good till here.

The problem is that when it reaches the submitted page, it is getting the following encoding:
https://example.com/dir1/page.php?var1=value1%26var2%3Dvalue2%26var3%3Dvalue3%26

Essentially, the & is getting %26, and = is becoming %3D.
I am aware that this is due to the inbuilt encodeURIComponent of HTML, but due to this encoding the form submission is failing.

I am looking for a way/method to receive the following in the submitted page (i.e. without encoding), so that it can be processed smoothly:

https://example.com/dir1/page.php?var1=value1&var2=value2&var3=value3&

PS: have explored existing threads like [Escaping ampersand in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url) & [Why does %26 get decoded to & when passed as a parameter to a JavaScript function from a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650676/why-does-26-get-decoded-to-when-passed-as-a-parameter-to-a-javascript-functio) & many more, but unable to find the answer.

Also tried the following as mentioned in [URL/HTML escaping/encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782988/url-html-escaping-encoding), but not working:

```
echo "<button value='value1&".htmlspecialchars($argument)."' type='submit' name='var1'>Send</button>";
```

If any existing answer exists, pls point me to it in the comment before marking this question down.
Thanks

Comment: Put these values individually in hidden fields in the form which the button is part of.

Comment: P.S. htmlspecialchars is for HTML-encoding to protect against XSS. It has nothing to do with URL-encoding. In PHP there's a separate [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function for that.

Comment: I've posted a full answer, with an example. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply put these values individually in hidden fields in the form which the button is part of.

e.g.

```
<form>
    <button type='submit' name='send'>Send</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="var1" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($val1)?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="var2" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($val2)?>">
</form>
```

The browser will then use these to create a properly-constructed and encoded URL for you automatically when the form is submitted.